# C++20 コンセプトで、特定の戻り値の型を持つメンバ関数を持つことを要求するにはどのようにすべきですか？

Tags: c++

A.f()はintを返していますが、もしコメントアウト部が入っているコードの場合は、boolでなければコンパイルエラーになります。これをコンセプトで要求したい（f()の戻り値をboolであることを要求したい)場合はどのようにすべきでしょうか？

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <concepts>

struct A{
    int f()
    {
        return 42;
    }
};

template<class T>
concept Printable = requires(T t){
    t.f();
};

template<typename T>
void PrintIfPrintable(T arg)
{
    if constexpr (Printable<T>){
        //bool a {arg.f()}; // コンパイルエラー
        std::cout << arg.f() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    PrintIfPrintable(A());
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`std::same_as`コンセプト](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/concepts/same_as.html)を使用して`t.f()`の戻り値が`bool`か判定する感じでしょうか？

```
template<class T>
concept Printable = std::same_as<decltype(std::declval<T>().f()), bool>;
```

Comment: 複数の条件を指定したい場合は、template<class T>
concept Printable = requires(T t){
    t.f();
} && std::same_as<decltype(std::declval<T>().f()), bool>;のように&&で条件を追加していくのが正攻法でしょうか？

Comment: @misaki はい `&&` ですね。ただし、`t.f()` が存在しなければ `std::same_as` は成立しないので省略しました。

Comment: FYI: requres式 `requires(T t){ { t.f() } -> std::same_as<bool>; };` と書くこともできます。複数条件を並べる場合には、そのままrequires式内に追記していくだけで済みます。

Answer (score 6):

（直接的な解決策はsayuriさん回答を参照ください。本回答は追加の情報提供となります。）

> C++20 コンセプトで、特定の戻り値の型を持つメンバ関数を持つことを要求するにはどのようにすべきですか？

関数テンプレート定義中の処理において該当メンバ関数`f()`の戻り値をどう扱うかに合わせて、2種類の回答がありえます。

- (1) 厳密に`bool`型を要求する。
- (2) `bool`型のように扱えればよい。

```cpp
template<class T>
concept Printable = requires(T t) {
    // (1) T::f()は厳密にbool型を返す
    { t.f() } -> std::same_as<bool>
};

template<class T>
concept Printable = requires(T t) {
    // (2) T::f()は「bool型に変換可能な型」を返す
    { t.f() } -> std::convertible_to<bool>
};
```

(1)のデメリットとして、`f()`の戻り値型が厳密に`bool`型を要求するため、例えば`const bool&`を返すようなケースでコンセプト`Printable`を満たさないと判定されます。

一方で(2)のデメリットとして、例示コードのような`int`→`bool`縮小変換をチェックしません。つまり`int`型は`bool`型に(明示)変換可能と判定されます。とはいえ、真偽値(`bool`)を要求する`if (t.f()) {...}`のような文脈での利用では、大抵はこのような判定で問題ないと思います。

---

> コメント：複数の条件を指定したい場合は、template concept Printable = requires(T t){ t.f(); } && std::same_as<decltype(std::declval().f()), bool>;のように&&で条件を追加していくのが正攻法でしょうか？

C++20コンセプトにおいては、下記いずれの書き方も同じ意味となります。

- `requires(T t){ t.f(); } && std::same_as<decltype(std::declval<T>().f()), bool>`
- `requires(T t){ { t.f() } -> std::same_as<bool>; }`

C++17以前の[SFINAE技法](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE)では、まず最初に式`t.f()`が有効であることを確認し、続いて式`t.f()`が型`bool`と等しいか否かを確認する必要がありました。（コメントはこの考え方を反映したものでしょう）

C++20コンセプトでは、定義中に登場する式`t.f()`が無効であればその時点で制約式全体が偽とみなされます。SFINAE技法のようにコンパイルエラーを引き起こさないため、より直接的な制約記述が可能となっています。

Comment: ある型とある型が変換可能かどうかというのはどこで定義されるのでしょうか。また、intやboolのようなプリミティブ？型だけじゃなくて、ユーザー定義したClass同士の変換可能性はどう定義するものなのでしょうか？

Comment: C++言語が提供する基本型間の型変換は、[標準変換(standard conversion)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/cpp/standard-conversions)ルールに従います。ユーザ定義クラスの場合は、変換コンストラクタ(`T::T(U)`など)や型変換演算子(`T::operator U()`など)を用いてある型から別の型への変換を実現します。